# Incorrect usage of UNION and INTO while Creating Procedure in MySql

Tags: mysql, procedure

While creating procedure following error occurs:

```
Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and INTO
```

My Procedure is:

```
    SET sql_mode=ORACLE;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE MARK_ATTENDANCE (IN EmployeeId INTEGER) 
    BEGIN
       DECLARE EmpShift INTEGER(10);
       DECLARE EmpMarkLoc INTEGER(10);
       SET EmpShift = 0;
       SET EmpMarkLoc = 0;

       SELECT ed.default_shift, sl.location_id INTO EmpShift,EmpMarkLoc
       FROM EMPLOYEE ed
       LEFT JOIN sublocation sl
       ON sl.sublocation_id = ed.sub_location_id
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ed.default_shift, sl.location_id 
       FROM EMPLOYEE ed
       RIGHT JOIN sublocation sl
       ON sl.sublocation_id = ed.sub_location_id
       WHERE sl.sublocation_id IS NULL
       AND emp_id = EmployeeId;
    END ;
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Actually I wanted a FULL OUTER JOIN and ended up on UNION ALL and tried to store output in some variables like `EmpShift` and `EmpMarkLoc` for further usage.

Comment: Without using 'INTO EmpShift,EmpMarkLoc' all is working fine but I need to hold selected values in some variables.

Comment: Got solution by hit and try :).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @EmpShift:=ed.default_shift,  @EmpMarkLoc:=sl.location_id
```

used above in place of

```
SELECT ed.default_shift, sl.location_id INTO EmpShift,EmpMarkLoc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the unioned queries in a derived table and select from there into the variables

```
SELECT u.default_shift,
       u.location_id
       INTO empshift,
            empmarkloc
       FROM (SELECT ed.default_shift,
                    sl.location_id
                    FROM employee ed
                         LEFT JOIN sublocation sl
                                   ON sl.sublocation_id = ed.sub_location_id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ed.default_shift,
                   sl.location_id 
                   FROM employee ed
                        RIGHT JOIN sublocation sl
                                   ON sl.sublocation_id = ed.sub_location_id
                   WHERE sl.sublocation_id IS NULL
                         AND emp_id = employeeid) u;
```

But be aware, if the unioned querys can select more than one row an assignment to scalar variables is problematic.

Comment: Thanks for quick answering and support and yes it will give "Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row" error.

Comment: While i used SELECT 'atsign'EmpShift:=ed.default_shift,  'atsign'EmpMarkLoc:=sl.location_id gives no such error and worked for me.